# Coldfusion Grid Fontsize

Tags: coldfusion

I am having trouble changing the font size of the text in the columns. I have used attribute fontsize and it does not work.

```
<cfform name="mainF">
        <cfgrid name="record" query="getRecords" format="html"> 
            <cfgridcolumn name="act" FONTSIZE="300" bold="yes" > 
            <cfgridcolumn name="sub" FONTSIZE="15"> 
            <cfgridcolumn name="Mon" FONTSIZE="15" DATAALIGN="CENTER"> 
            <cfgridcolumn name="date_of" fontsize="15" DATAALIGN="CENTER"> 
            <cfgridcolumn name="Desc" width="510" display="yes" fontsize="15"> 

        </cfgrid>

    </cfform>
```

Comment: Which columns aren't working; all those at size 15, or the one at size 300?  Or all of them?  What size(s) are you getting instead?  What does it look like?

Comment: All of them are not working. I just typed in 300 to see if it makes any different, but it doesn't. I am not sure why none of the columns work.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, I never could get that to work.  I had to do some digging, and ended up using CSS.

```
/* should set the whole grid */
.x-grid3{
    font:Consolas;
}

/* grid title area */
.x-panel-header{
    font-size:18px;
    font:Consolas;
}

/* column headers */
.x-grid3-hd-inner{
    font-size:12px;
}

/* cells with data */
.x-grid3-cell-inner{
    font-size:14px;
}
```

I used 'Inspect Element with Firebug' to find the different areas.  The grid itself is built (roughly) with a combination of table elements for the structure, and div elements for data (divs area used for other things too).

Good Luck